# Javascript - jquery - selecting multiple change events

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create some calculations using a wordpress forms plugin that a customer insists on using (due to integrations with other plugins). I have created the code which fires on an onchange field event.  I want to be able to trigger the code from multiple form fields events however.

See below - item meta[76] onchange fires the scrip. How can i modify this to enable other fields to fire the script as well (ie item meta[34] || item meta[43]). Is it possible in the select one statement? The strange IDs are due to the plugin. Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('select[name="item_meta[76]"]').change(function(){
    var val1 = $("select[name='item_meta[76]']").val();
    var myArea = $("#field_f4wns").val() * $("#field_ymo4z").val();
    var myTotalArea = $("#field_xuyzx").val(); 
    var myToolPrice = "#field_8v27o";
    var myBoardPrice = "#field_ku0w8";
        if (val1 == "One Layer"){ 
                if (myArea > 0 && myArea < 5000) {
                $(myToolPrice).val(20);
                }...... and many other calculations follow.
```

Comment: Ok tried that and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a delegate listener with an appropriate selector and make use of the `this` variable.

1. You have one function, and N elements that need the logic performed.  Don't attach a listener to every single element.  That means lots of extra memory and code tracking (and potential source of bugs) for your web app.  Instead, use a [delegate listener](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

   ```
   // "bad" (not wrong; could be better)
   jQuery('select[name=a],select[name=b],sele...').change(...

   // "good" (the specific scenario dictates best)
   jQuery('body').on('change', 'select[name=a],select[name=b],sele...', function (evt) {
   ```

   The first example attaches a copy of the function to the change event of every single element matched in the selector.  In the example above, any `<select name="a">` or `<select name="b">`.  The second example attaches a **single** listener to the change event on the body element, but only actually executes if one of the selectors matches.  Same effect, much less memory, much less churn for your JS engine, and presumably now only a single place for you to worry about generating your comma-separated selector.
2. Understand how jQuery abuses the `this` keyword.  Whenever jQuery calls back to an event listener, it sets the `this` variable to the actual element of the event.  So, in your code above, you have this:

   ```
   $('select[name="item_meta[76]"]').change(function(){
       var val1 = $("select[name='item_meta[76]']").val();
   ```

   That is wholly too much work.  Consider:

   ```
   $('select[name="item_meta[76]"]').change(function(){
       var val1 = $(this).val();
   ```

With this last tidbit, you should be able to write a single, more general, delegate listener that works for you and is easier to alter as appropriate.

Comment: This is also very helpful - i love the optimisation you have applied. I cant thank everyone enough for responding.  I now have the script behaving as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple selector in for calling function on event as:

```
$('selector1','selector2','selector3',...).change(function(){
  // your code
});
```

Or you can give common class to all the element and define the jQuery function as:

```
$('.common_class').change(function(){
      // your code
});
```

Additionally, inside the function, you are using that selector again to get value:

```
var val1 = $("select[name='item_meta[76]']").val();
```

So in this case, you can replace your static selector with this keyword as:

```
var val1 = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. Being relatively new to javascript (i struggle with selectors atm) overcoming small hurdles like this is a big help.